# When is a brake hard line 'kinked'

Tags: brakes

Would anyone be able to tell me if this brake line is 'kinked' ? I am replacing the hard line to the rear of the vehicle and I dont want to take any chances.

https://photos.app.goo.gl/KKwRXGBTTXJDVZJPA

Thanks

Comment: If you want to bend pipes and avoid damage like that then buy and use a pipe bender. Then you can do gentle sweeps to tight curves - makes the job much easier and more professional, also means you can do tight detail where needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the line in the picture wasn't quite kinked.. However Its hard to tell via a picture if fluid flow would be restricted or not. 
The only way you'd be able to tell properly is if the brakes were working evenly on that axle. 
If I were you I'd just run another length, but If you're wanting/willing to leave it like that, you'll at least have to have the brakes checked on a rolling road to make sure the brake balance is ok.